# books to teach K-12 math/science via real-world approach?

Tags: reference-request

I volunteered abroad in rural Ethiopia and a village in a remote mountainous area of China. I plan to return to both places and teach for as long as I can make it work. I want to focus on STEM, but first I would like to reteach myself math and science from pre-school all the way to college-level math, such as Calculus, Physics, etc., so that I am confidently able to teach them. Almost none of them speak English, so I will be teaching them that as well along the way, since I can speak Amharic, Mandarin and Cantonese.

BUT I would like to teach them from a real-world approach. I've seen the website "Mathalicious" and it is inspiring. But I would like to get a set of textbooks that are widely used in academia to get them from a pre-school level of understanding of these subjects, where the only required prerequisite is to understand English, to the advanced levels. And I have also seen websites like Khan Academy but I would like something that is more official and mimics the curriculum progression flow that is standard in public/private school settings. Eventually, I hope to find a way to get at least a few children here somehow.

What I've found so far: 
http://www.doe.mass.edu/frameworks/

This website lists objectives and goals, but doesn't list any textbooks to follow.

http://www.hawaiipublicschools.org/TeachingAndLearning/StudentLearning/CommonCoreStateStandards/Pages/home.aspx

This is the only state website I've seen so far that includes state-approved textbook materials that I can go through. It only lists Reading and math so far and the list is not really detailed at all though.

So, to be as specific as possible, I am searching for a list of good (text)books (based on your professional experience) that I can work through to arrive at advanced math and science.

Hopefully, I can get an answer like, "Follow this progression of books "xxx". Ask here if you need help figuring out how to apply it to the 'real world'."

Comment: whats' curriculum may depend on country, I didn't even learn algebra until grade 9 for example.  didn't learn set theory until I annoyed the math community online a lot. etc.

Comment: I am referring to the US curriculum, any state will do. I chose Massachusetts because it widely seen as having the best public school system in America.

Comment: okay sorry I live in Canada and I'm stupid.

Comment: Ah, please excuse me. I misunderstood your question, I apologize. Now, I see what you were asking about. The curriculum of other countries will work also if you can include textbook recommendations that follow the curriculum. Yes, you are correct other countries also have wonderful curriculums that are great to follow.

Comment: it was actually more of a statement, but anyways I don't think websites like primes.utm.edu or even wolfram.mathworld would have links to easy books.

Comment: My search is for the titles, the material does not have to be open-source or freely available. I am willing to pay out of my own pocket for the resources.

Comment: http://primes.utm.edu/references/refs.cgi?authorindex  might come in help for later math.

Comment: There is an Exchange or Overflow site on this network of sites that is devoted to math education, mainly for teachers. I suggest you cross-post this Q there and also on MathOverflow.